# Major mode map in emacs

Tags: major-mode

How to print, all file extensions & the mapped major modes (and possibly minor modes...) in emacs?
like this,

```
*.js     js-mode
*.json   js-mode
*.c      c-mode
```

Which global map variable contains this information?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That information is a `F1 v auto-mode-alist` away which displays the variable `auto-mode-alist` that holds the associations between file names and major modes.  As its docstring points out similiar lists playing a role would be `interpreter-mode-alist` (which uses shebangs) and the more generic `magic-mode-alist`.